# Converting mac node script to windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell

I have a postinstall node script that copies previously run scripts into my npm-scripts folder.  However, this only works for Mac.  I need to have it work for Windows as well so I am creating a new file that will run 1 for windows or the one listed below for Mac.

```
`cp ../node_modules/some-components/npm-scripts/*.js ../npm_scripts`
```

I'm not seeing a clear way to convert the syntax to be usable by a windows machine as well as whether to use copy or robocopy.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Suggestion: Create a JavaScript for copying the file, e.g. via `fs`. This is obviously platform independent.

Comment: I am doing this but am unclear on the Windows syntax which is why I showed what needed to be converted from mac.  The basic format is this.

    `const exec = require('./exec');

    const platformCheck = () => {
      if (process.platform === 'win32') {
        exec('windows thing here');
    }
    exec('mac thing here)
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `copy.js` file which performs the copy platform-independently via a Node.js API (i.e. do not rely on Windows or Unix-specific shell commands `cp` or `copy`). My suggestion: Use [`fs-extra`](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra#copy), which also handles copying directories, in contrast to the included `fs`.

```
var fs = require('fs-extra'); // add to your dependencies via 'npm install fs-extra --save'
var path = require('path');

fs.copySync(
      path.resolve(__dirname, '../path/to/source', 
      path.resolve(__dirname, '../path/to/destination'));
```

Comment: I understand now.  Thanks for your answer!